# Mocking external responses with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

I have a method that calls various services and uses their output later. Something like this:

```
myOutput1 = await _apiCaller.Call(() => _myService.someCall(someData));
myOutput2 = await _apiCaller.Call(() => _myService.anotherCall(otherData));
```

I would like to just mock the responses to these with NSubstitute, without waiting for the calls.

However, it doesn't look like NSubstitute catches the internal function call (e.g. `someCall`, `anotherCall`), so I have to mock the API caller. This is a problem in two ways: I can't seem to differentiate between the two function inputs, and more broadly, even properly mock the caller.

I am doing the following:

```
sub._apiCaller.Call(default).ReturnsForAnyArgs(Task.FromResult(myMockData));
```

But still get a `null` result in `myOutput#`.

What is the correct way to mock the results of such calls, and is there a way to differentiate the internal function call?

Comment: You should be able to mock the call to the service. You are not showing pieces of code that are relevant to look into your specific case, and I assume the instance being tested is the _apiCaller. I've done things like this with NSubstitute many times. There is something you are not showing that is getting in the way. Please add the rest of the code that is relevant to the test.

Comment: You are correct, I copied some code and didn't notice that I was substituting the API caller. Instantiating it solved the problem. Your example is still useful though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to what you are suggesting. The idea will be the same in terms of how you go about mocking the internal service.

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private IMyService _myService;
        private ApiCaller _apiCaller;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            _apiCaller = new ApiCaller();
            _myService = Substitute.For<IMyService>();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestMethod1()
        {
            _myService.SomeCall(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(190);
            var output = await _apiCaller.Call(() => _myService.SomeCall(4));
            Assert.AreEqual(190, output);
        }
    }

    public class ApiCaller
    {
        public async Task<T> Call<T>(Func<T> service)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => service.Invoke());
        }
    }

    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public int SomeCall(int x)
        {
            return x * 8;
        }
    }

    public interface IMyService
    {
        int SomeCall(int x);
    }
```

Because the mock is returning immediately, the call is not being actually awaited.